# Flipping a coin in sequence - (unconventional)

Tags: probability

I have a question that can be described as an unconventional case of flipping a coin.

Suppose for a coin, the probability of showing Heads is 0.4462 and showing Tails has a probability of 0.4586. In this strange case, suppose the coin can also stand on the Edge with a probability of 0.0952.

Can someone please tell me what is the probability of having heads n times in a row in 70 tries? it can include showing the edge as well: (HHHHHHHHH...n or HHHHEHEHHHHHEH...n or any other combinations of E-H that has n number of H in it).

I know the question looks strange but is solves a very important issue for me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If $n=6$, do you want a stretch with $6$ heads and maybe some edge, or a stretch with $6$ heads and/or edge?

Comment: I am interested in 5<n<10

Comment: and stretches of heads and/or edges

Comment: for me a stretch like: HEEEEEEEEH counts as n=2

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that's actually not true since he wants HEEEHEE to count as 2 heads. I can't think of any reasonable way to model that once you have merged heads and edges.

Comment: Ooops, misread the question, yes. @DRF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with a recurrence. Suppose the three probabilities for each outcome for each coin are $P_H, P_E, P_T$ adding up to $1$. Consider:

- $f(t,0,n) = P_E f(t-1,0,n) + P_T \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(t-1,i,n)$
- $f(t,r,n) = P_T f(t-1,r,n) + P_H f(t-1,r-1,n) \text{ for } 0 \lt r \lt n$
- $f(t,n,n) = f(t-1,n,n) + P_H f(t-1,r-1,n) $

starting with $f(0,0,n) = 1$ and $f(0,r,n)=0$ for $0 \lt r$.

You want $f(70, n, n)$, which is easily found, for example with a spreadsheet.

Comment: For example it seems $f(70,5,5)\approx 0.620801945$ and $f(70,6,6)\approx 0.364320867$, while $f(70,10,10)\approx 0.023661258$

Comment: could you please elaborate what "r" is?

Comment: $r$ is the number of Hs in the current run (ignoring any Es), except that $r=n$ is absorbing.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_H,p_E,p_T$ be your probabilities.

This can be seen as a Markov process, where the states are labeled $i=0,1,2,\dots,n$ where $n$ means we got $n$ in a row somewhere, and the state $i<n$ means we are currently in a run of $i$ heads. Then the probability transition is:

$$p_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1&i=j=n\\
p_E&i=j\neq 0,n\\
p_T&j=0,i\neq 0\\
p_T+p_E&i=j=0\\
p_H&j=i+1
\end{cases}$$

So, when $n=3$, for example, the matrix is:

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}p_T+p_E&p_H&0&0\\
p_T&p_E&p_H&0\\
p_T&0&p_E&p_H\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

You want to find the probability that you are in state $n$ after $m=70$ tosses, starting in the state $0$.  Letting $P=(p_{ij})$, this amounts to finding the $0n$ entry in $P^m$.

You can use the process of repeated squaring to make calculating $P^{70}$ on fewer matrix multiplications, or if there is some easy way to diagonalize the matrix.

(The method of repeated squaring computes:

$$P^2,P^4,p^8,P^{16},P^{32},P^{64}$$

in six matrix multiplications, then computes $P^{70}=P^{64}P^{4}P^2$.)

I assume this is roughly the same answer as the previous one, but framing it as matrix exponentiation gives you an ability to compute faster for large $m$. But if you need all the values in between, you still need to do $m$ multiplications.

And software packages are really good at computing $P^m$ for matrices $P$.

Letting $$A_T=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\\A_H=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
We can write: $$P=p_EI + p_TA_T+p_HA_H$$

We have that $A_T^2=A_T$, for example, which might help simplify $A^n$. It's not as simple as binomial theorem, unfortunately, since $A_T$ and $A_H$ don't commute, but there might be something you could do here.

In particular, diagonalizing $P$ is the same as diagonalizing $p_HA_H+p_TA_T$ then adding $p_E$ to the diagonal.

If you know the eigenvalues of $P$, $\{\lambda_i\}$, and they are distinct, the there is a set of $\alpha_i$ such that the number you are looking for is:

$$\sum_i \alpha_i \lambda_i^m$$

Since we know the number is $0$ for $m=0,1,\dots,n-1$ and $p_H^n$ for $m=n$, we can solve for the $\alpha_i$. This will be a great way to compute an asymptotic - the rate at which the probability approaches $1$.

(If the eigenvalues are not distinct, the formula will be different, but a similar formula exists.)

For example, when $n=4$, the estimate is about:

$$1-1.08334\cdot 0.968788^m$$

For $m=20$, this estimate gives $0.423314$ and the "exact" calculation gives $0.423318$.

For $m=70$ and $n<20$ the value of the estimate has agreed with the "exact" value up to eight digits.

This table computes for varied $n$  the exact and estimated values using this tech and the $\lambda,\alpha$ so that we estimate the computation as $1-\alpha\lambda^m$.

```
 N lambda     alpha       exact(70)    est(70)
 1 0.55380000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000
 2 0.83165462 1.16597047 0.99999710 0.99999710
 3 0.92996178 1.13228001 0.99297719 0.99297719
 4 0.96878766 1.08733752 0.88186837 0.88186837
 5 0.98549884 1.05423636 0.62080194 0.62080194
 6 0.99309343 1.03259610 0.36432087 0.36432087
 7 0.99666182 1.01913855 0.19354383 0.19354383
 8 0.99837256 1.01102553 0.09791662 0.09791662
 9 0.99920261 1.00624949 0.04839934 0.04839934
10 0.99960818 1.00349307 0.02366126 0.02366126
11 0.99980716 1.00192896 0.01150635 0.01150635
12 0.99990500 1.00105421 0.00558074 0.00558074
13 0.99995318 1.00057102 0.00270293 0.00270293
14 0.99997692 1.00030693 0.00130799 0.00130799
15 0.99998862 1.00016389 0.00063258 0.00063258
16 0.99999439 1.00008701 0.00030578 0.00030578
17 0.99999723 1.00004596 0.00014774 0.00014774
18 0.99999864 1.00002417 0.00007135 0.00007135
19 0.99999933 1.00001267 0.00003444 0.00003444
```

From data, it looks like if $m>3n$ then the estimate is correct within seven or eight digits.